# regular expression search in notepad++ or text pad

Tags: regex, notepad++, newline, multiline, textpad

I want to be able to search a pattern like 'CREATE TABLE  ' followed by any expression include newline and ending with );

So  it should be able to select following 2 create table stamtement one after other.

```
create table tab1 ( col1 number,

col2 date);

create table tab3 ( col1 number,

col2 date,

col3 number);
```

I did tried create table .* but I am not able to include newline .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do:

```
create table [^;]*;
```

**check the matches newline checkbox**

Comment: Thanks. It worked in Notepad++ :-).  Could you please briefly tell me what does [^;]*; mean.   Also, any way to make it work in textpad.

Comment: @user3204310 `[^;]*` is regex, means any number of not `;` chars. google regex for details. I don't have textpad, don't know if it supports regex. in fact I don't have notepad++ either. but I knew that it supports regex and has that checkbox. ;)

Comment: It's not mandatory to check `dot matches newlines` because you don't have dot in your regex. But you have to check `Regular expression`.